# how to get rid of Eclipse white space characters

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse: I turned on hidden characters now I can’t turn off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330620/eclipse-i-turned-on-hidden-characters-now-i-cant-turn-off)

I use Eclipse (3.72) to develop Android apps.  I accidentally bumped something against my keyboard and now there are these light gray formatting characters showing.  They are very distracting.  I've looked everywhere I can think of on how to get rid of them.

I restored defaults in the editor to no avail.  I've googled everywhere only to find reccos to "uncheck the remove whitespace characters" but that is no where to be found.

Help!
thanks, Gary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors-Uncheck 'Show whitespace characters'

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut for toggling "show whitespace". You can check the shortcut by going to the path mentioned below. If you would like to toggle "show whitespace" try the shortcut that is listed for your version of eclipse.

You can set this shortcut by going to `window -> general -> keys` and then searching for "show whitespace" and you can set the shortcut there.