# How to remove unwanted symbols in the background of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently rested on my keyboard on my keyboard and somehow managed to change the appearance of Eclipse without even noticing...

[I see these strange symbols that are beginning to annoy me that weren't there before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hfdy.png)

If they are of any importance could anyone please explain what they are and why they are important, and also how to remove it from Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2461515/3981536

Comment: @redflar3 Thankyou, solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors

Uncheck the "Show whitespace characters" option on the right side of the page, then click "Apply" at the bottom of the page.