# what is this from eclipse?? looks like arrow..>>

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

What are these gray dots and arrows. I want to remove this.

Please help.

Comment: It is because [you have turned on whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330620/eclipse-i-turned-on-hidden-characters-now-i-cant-turn-off). `>>` means a tab character.

Comment: Do you understand what the gray dots mean? So what other "thing" can be used for indentation, but isn't indicated by a dot?

Comment: Tabs & spaces & newlines. You have the display of invisual interpunction on. Because of the mix between spaces and tabs, maybe better do a Reformat in the menu. Explore the settings.

Comment: this happens when you copy-paste from somewhere. try to type it manually then you should be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the option `Show whitespace characters` under `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors` is selected, you would see this highlighting for whitespace characters (Space, Tab, New line).

You just need to uncheck this option to disable highlighting.

Comment: you save my life thanks alot